# The entrypoint (public/index.php) in Symfony 6 - how it works?

Tags: php, symfony6

So the entrypoint file in the Symfony 6 framework (`public/index.php`) has a construct which I don't understand.

Below is the whole content of the file:

```php
<?php

use App\Kernel;

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    return new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);
};
```

What I don't understand is the usage of the anonymous function. As we are at the very top level I don't know how it is executed and where does it return it's result.

Comment: Turn on xDebug and do step-debugging to see what's happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is simple.

As you can see you are not asking for a standard autoload of composer

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

But you are requiring

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';
```

This file is generated by [symfony/runtime](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/runtime.html)

The operation is simple, I'll give you an example

File **index.php** (entry point):

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/runtime.php';

return function (array $context){
    print_r($context);
    return 1;
};
```

File **runtime.php** (runtime):

```php
<?php
$app = require $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];

$app = $app(['context_variable'=>1]);
```

What Happnes:

1. When the index is called it requires the runtime
2. The runtime takes the variable 'SCRIPT_FILENAME' which is populated with the path of the index
3. The autoload file then makes a require_once of the executed file and passes it some parameters
4. Since in the index the runtime is called via require_once this will prevent files from calling each other recursively

I hope I have been exhaustive, otherwise please ask me.